# Error contacting API, com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:com.google.android.gms.api.ApiException: 13: Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have an app which I have released an Alpha version.

I am using the Places SDK for Android, Mobile Crash Reporting API, Firebase Services API, Places API, Maps SDK for Android in my APP. I have set the API restrictions so that the Key use these APIs from the App.

I have also set the **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** for the keystore which I have created.

I have added the key in the manifest file like below.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
```

I have also added the version number of the google playstore services.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Still I am getting the "Error contacting API, `com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:com.google.android.gms.api.ApiException: 13: Error`

When I do a debug run from the Android Studio, I don't get the error. I get the error when I try from the Alpha release from the playstore.

In the API console, I see that Places SDK for Android is the one that gives errors, and they are `403 errors`.

Any ideas on what else should I do?

Is there a way to check what is the key that is being requested or being sent to Google for verification?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set **no restrictions** in your API access. Just set it to none.

[image]

Comment: But that would be wrong right? It should be set to Android Apps right?

Comment: Yh. But somehow had same issue though I was sending request from android but it wasn't working so I had to set restriction to then it worked.